# Angular: Using filter in controller to set an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this example of a json with many records but let's assume name is unique. I want to just filter out an object by name in the controller so my html don't have to iterate through all the records using ng-repeat all the time.

```
{
"records": [
  {
    "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "City" : "Berlin",
    "Country" : "Germany"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "City" : "Luleå",
    "Country" : "Sweden"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "City" : "México D.F.",
    "Country" : "Mexico"
  }
]
}
```

Ideally within my html I can use the filtered object like this:

```
<p> {{ filteredObj.Name}} </p>
```

My controller looks like this. The line where I am applying the filter is not working and I can't spot the reason.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('customers.json').success(function (data) {
    //This is where I am doing it wrong when I try to filter out the object I need
    $scope.filteredObj = $filter('filter')(data.records, {name: "Alfreds Futterkiste");
  });
}]);
```

How can I use the $filter function correctly in the controller?

Comment: Have you tried? `<p> {{ records | filter : { Name: 'Alfreds Futterkiste' } }} </p>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to inject `$filter`.
2. Also `$filter` returns an array so you need to pick the first element (ideally you should be checking if there are any results as well).
3. And lastly the 2nd parameter to the filter should have `Name` (instead of `name`)

So you'd finally have something like this

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$filter', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $http.get('customers.json').success(function (data) {
    //This is where I am doing it wrong when I try to filter out the object I need
    $scope.filteredObj = $filter('filter')(data.records, { Name: "Alfreds Futterkiste" })[0];
  });
}]);
```